# Discord.js memberCount in Channelname by role (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Actually i am learning Javascript / node.js
I registered on this site because i am stucking at creating a discord bot.
Well, everything is fine and works, just one problem:

My Bot basically counts and updates the counter for Users in a Channel Name.
But the live update for a user by a role isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  let IGuild = client.guilds.cache.get("703237714413355019");
// User counter
  let memberCount = IGuild.memberCount;
  let channelCountUsers = IGuild.channels.cache.get('709859603793576056');
      channelCountUsers.setName('Users: '+ memberCount)
// Admins
  let adminID = '707261958243483698';
  let memberCountAdmins = IGuild.roles.cache.get(adminID).members.size;
  let channelCountAdmins = IGuild.channels.cache.get('709889840338042903');
      channelCountAdmins.setName('Admins: ' + memberCountAdmins)
});
// update User counter <- WORKS
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member=>{
    let IGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('703237714413355019');
    let memberCount =  IGuild.memberCount;
    let channelCountUsers = IGuild.channels.cache.get('709859603793576056');
        channelCountUsers.setName('Users: ' + memberCount)
   }) 
// update Admin counter <- DOES NOT WORK :(
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member=>{
    let IGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('703237714413355019');
    let adminID = "707261958243483698";
    let memberCount = IGuild.roles.cache.get(adminID).members.size;
    let channelCountAdmins = IGuild.channels.cache.get('709889840338042903');
        channelCountAdmins.setName('Admins: ' + memberCount)
   }) 


   client.on('guildMemberRemove', member =>{
    let IGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('703237714413355019');
      let memberCount =  IGuild.memberCount;
      let channelCountUsers = IGuild.channels.cache.get('709859603793576056');
        channelCountUsers.setName('Users: ' + memberCount)
   })
```

So all is what I need to live update the "Admins Counter" or the "Counter by a Role".

Greetings and sorry for posting my noob stuff here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is [`guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) does not check for role updates, for that you're going to have to use [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate)

Also, you have 2 `guildMemberAdd` events, you should only have 1 of each event.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', member=>{
    let IGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('703237714413355019');
    let adminID = "707261958243483698";
    let adminCount = IGuild.roles.cache.get(adminID).members.size;
    let channelCountAdmins = IGuild.channels.cache.get('709889840338042903');
        channelCountAdmins.setName('Admins: ' + adminCount)
})
```

Comment: i tried that, but that didn't work.

So, when i restart the bot the admin counts correctly.
But i try to update these stats when i give a role to a user

Comment: Sorry, I just re-wrote my answer, that should fix it